# SMTP vs POP3. Why use POP3?

Tags: email, smtp, pop3

My question is why to use SMTP for sending and POP3 for receiving messages when SMTP can do both send and receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because SMTP requires the recipant to be ready to receive the message directly after it has been send, where POP3 is able to store the message temporarly somewhere else until the recipant is ready to accept the message.